# Great Examples of an Eerie (or not) Memory Flashback

Tags: examples

What are some good examples of an eerie (or not) memory flashback (or flashforward)?

Comment: for radio or video purpose? It depends on time mostly and type of flashback. Music is our best friend. Like Ameli childhood, for example. If it something short associate it with pad sound like in F.E.A.R. and speech freq and room changes. 

Comment: Film purpose, examples of film flashbacks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the movies mentioned I remember 'Seven Pounds' having some subtle but beautiful sequences - for every time the Will Smith character thought about his family and the accident.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the partial-memory sequences in the Bourne movies are pretty cool. Also any of the "Harry's Rules" flashbacks in Dexter.

Comment: Agreed on both, though the location sound for a couple of the Dexter ones is frighteningly noisy.  You can clearly hear the gates.  I suppose that big series TV turnarounds don't really leave much room for finesse. 

Answer (score 0):

Hitchcock flicks are full of them, like [this](http://fan.tcm.com/_Alfred-Hitchcock-about-his-collaboration-with-Dali-on-Spellbound/VIDEO/967772/66470.html) one from Spellbound designed by Salvador Dali.

All of the movie Memento.

Answer (score 0):

The new Nightmare on Elm Street did a wonderful job of transporting a listener from a dream into reality, back to a dream, etc.

The Ring had some good eerie flashbacks.

I like the Gladiator flashbacks and flashforwards of him going to heaven and seeing his family again.

Lord of the Rings - Return of the King - the whole intro scene and fight between pre-Smeagol and the other hobbit.

Didn't Apocalypse Now have some great scenes of this nature?

Google is your friend:

Butterfly Effect

The Fugitive

Basic

The General's Daughter

Minority Report

Casablanca

I Am Legend

Jacob's Ladder

Vanilla Sky

The Notebook

Fight Club

Benjamin Button

Forest Gump

Answer (score 0):

In Shane Meadow's [Dead Man's Shoes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419677/) there are a lot of memory flashbacks. They play a pivotal role in the film and are realised by using grainy black and white for the visuals and a very subtle HPF, some reverberation and a bit of delay for the audio. Very simple, yet very effective.